# pointing by return value

Tags: c++, class, accessor

Assume we have a two classes

```
class A
{
    public:
        Course ( int num ) ;
        int getAnum();

        int num;
}


A::A( int num )
{
    this->num = num;
} 

int A::getAnum()
{
    return this->num;
}
```

and the other class

```
class B
{
    public:
        B ( A * a  = NULL);
        A * getA();      
    A * a;
}


B::B( Course * a )
{
    this->a = new A;
    this->a = a;
}
A * B::getA() { return this->a; }
```

in the main

```
A* a = new A(12);
B* b = new B(a);
```

and the question is how can I print the num

```
cout << b.getA->getAnum();
```

or

```
 cout <<b.a->getAnum();
```

Which one is the correct? Can I point another function by return value? What happens in both code samples and why? Don't pay attention the syntax mistakes please. And sorry for the inappropriate code and bad English. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: How many are compilation errors in your code snippet!!

Comment: @Desolator: I count four. How many did you get?

Comment: how long will it take to find out why b.getA()->getAnum() is seg-faulting because the B object default-constructed with a NULL A? You may wish to ponder this design awhile longer.

Comment: Your `B::B` body looks wrong.

Comment: come on i said just ignore that. I just want to learn can i use a return value as a data member.

Answer (score 0):

cout << b.a->GetAnum(); since your a variable is public, it can be accessed.

Comment: what if the data members are private

Comment: Just because it's public doesn't mean you should use it. In fact you should use `GetAnum()` instead and make `a` private instead. **Disclaimer:** It is not _always_ appropriate to use getters and setters. I recommend it here because the given example is lacking in detail and context. Sometimes it will not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code that by solving them you may find more useful things that finding your answer, but beside that in C++ in order to call a function you need to use `operator()`, so you should write `b->getA()->getAnum()` instead of `b->getA->getAnum()`. In your version `b->getA` is a function and you can't apply `operator->` to it! but `b->getA()` call that function and return a `A*` that you can use it to call `getAnum()`